# How to create an angled navigation using images

Tags: html, css, navigation

[image: Multi level navigation]

This image is a navigation consisting of two DIVS with an image inside. DIV's are square and the problem here is that the navigation is angled. Currently, I can hover over the What we do tab (highlighted in black) but cannot get to the Who we are tab because it is covered by the What we do DIV. I could change the Z-index but this poses another issue in that then you cannot click on the center of the What we do box.

I would use CSS3 rotation however this site needs to be compatible with browsers dating back as far as god awful IE6. I wonder if anyone can help me and I look forward to hearing suggestions?!

Comment: The only solution I see for your problem is the use of an imagemap. That is backwards compatible.

Comment: Css rotation could work but it wont be backwards compatible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just updating all answers on stackoverflow for my account - In the end I created anchor links and just made sure that I had them set to position relative and the correct z-index so they dont overlap eachother. Unfortunately when presented with a challenge like this often the only solution is by introducing flash or JavaScript which is often not ideal.

Answer (score 0):

Impossible to do this with html/css, you need some flash-based solution. I'm sorry.

The reason is that CSS2.1 positioning is only calculated on either a vertical or a horizontal basis. There is no notion of angle.

Answer (score 0):

Can try using javascript/jQuery to detect the position of the cursor & switch z-index.